# How to only download packages with chocolatey?

Tags: windows, download, chocolatey

I'm trying to download chocolatey packages to the current directory but so for I managed to do [this](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/108#issuecomment-1703071625) using the command below but it's very verbose and downloads the package(s) in a complicated directory path name (`$env:temp/chocolatey/ChocolateyScratch/$myPackageName/$version/tools/`) :

`choco install --noop -y -r notepad3 cdburnerxp`

Comment: Have you followed the suggestion in reply to your GitHub comment?

Comment: @pauby I prefer to post my question where it can easily be found be search engines on well know sites such as github or stackoverflow. Or else, I'm not sure I'm going to be able to find answer the answer on seach engines in the near future.

Comment: If your goal is to get an answer to your question, it would seem the best way to do that would be to go to the place that has been provided, where the people who can provide the answer can be found. Having the question here makes the question searchable, but if there is no answer at the end of the search, it would be frustrating.

Comment: @pauby You are right, once I get an answer on [Discord](https://discord.com/app), I will post it here.